# Is it possible to import existing CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer into another project using CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I have a Cognito Authorizer already created in API Gateway with a project and in another project I want to import and use that Authorizer.

I created it using `CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer`:

```
    const auth = new CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer(this, "CognitoAuthorizer", {
      cognitoUserPools: [cognitoUserPool],
    });
```

Is it possible to import that `CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer` already created in another project or strictly I have to create a new one?

Comment: I believe you can use the CfnMethod construct to pass an authorizerId in. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.CfnMethod.html#authorizerid-1

Comment: I also believe you can just add the authorizer to the addMethod function on your resource like this:
....addMethod('PUT', myIntegration, {
    authorizationType: AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
    authorizer: { authorizerId: "someauthorizerid" }
})

Comment: @osekmedia Yes, the second option is what I am trying to do but to do that I need to be able to import the existing AuthorizerId and not create a new one

Comment: Can you pass the ID in from your stage file? Not ideal but should work. Would be nice if they had a lookup option for authorizers. I guess you could also write the ID to a secret or param and reference that in this project.